# ReactJs - Headless UI Transition Not Working With Modal Dialog

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I am using ReactJS with TailWindCSS and HeadlessUI. I copied the Modal Dialog code from the official website, and extracted it into its own component. The modal dialog appears "instantly" without transition, even though I have the "Transition.Child" component.

```
import { Fragment, useRef } from "react";
import { Dialog, Transition } from "@headlessui/react";

const ModalDialog = ({ open, setOpen, title, buttonText, children }) => {
  const cancelButtonRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as="div"
        className="relative z-10"
        initialFocus={cancelButtonRef}
        onClose={setOpen}
      >
        <Transition.Child
          as={Fragment}
          enter="ease-out duration-300"
          enterFrom="opacity-0"
          enterTo="opacity-100"
          leave="ease-in duration-200"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0"
        >
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
        </Transition.Child>

        <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
          <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
            <Transition.Child
              as={Fragment}
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
              enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
            >
              <Dialog.Panel className="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg p-6 pb-4">
                <Dialog.Title
                  as="h3"
                  className="text-left font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900 mb-4"
                >
                  {title}
                </Dialog.Title>

                {children}
                <div className="px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse sm:px-6">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-red-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-red-500 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto"
                    onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
                  >
                    {buttonText}
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="mt-3 inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto"
                    onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
                    ref={cancelButtonRef}
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </div>
              </Dialog.Panel>
            </Transition.Child>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition.Root>
  );
};
export default ModalDialog;
```

This is me adding more details since it insists that I do.
This is me adding more details since it insists that I do.

Comment: Check the code from official docs and modify it accordingly https://headlessui.com/react/dialog

and check if the values that you're passing through props are correct or not